# Using a QGenericMatrix as an attribute for another class

Tags: c++, qt

Qt has a class named `QGenericMatrix`. It's defined as follows :

```
template <int N, int M, typename T>
class QGenericMatrix
{...}
```

I would like to use it as an attribute `colorMatrix` in a class of my own `MyClass` and then initialize it in its constructor like this :

```
MyClass::MyClass(int n, int m)
{
  colorMatrix = new QGenericMatrix<n, m, QColor>;
}
```

However the syntax is probably very incorrect. How should I write the declaration in the header file and the constructor ?

Comment: Are N, M and T known during compile time? Template parameters must be known at compile time. As such as variables like ```int n``` cannot be used to init templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since template params must be known at compile time, you have two options:

1. Fix the matrix size and type within MyClass. e.g

   ```
   class MyClass {
     QGenericMatrix<2, 3, QColor> colorMatrix;
   }
   ```
2. Define MyClass as a template that takes the same template params as QGenericMatrix and instantiate colorMatrix using MyClass' template params. Like so:

   ```
   template<int N, int M, typename T>
   class MyClass {
     MyClass() { // init }
     T entry(int i, int j);

     QGenericMatrix<N, M, T> colorMatrix;
   }

   template<int N, int M, typename T>
   T MyClass::entry(int i, int j) { return colorMatrix(i, j); }
   ```

   Naturally in this case, MyClass will have to be instantiated with template params which again must be known at compile time.

   ```
   MyClass<2, 3, QColor> myClass;
   ```

Comment: Right, option 2 is what I was looking for. However, how do I write the constructor for this ? Do I need to add anything ?
What about a `getColorMatrix` method ? Can I write `QGenericMatrix<N, M, T> MyClass<N,M,T>::getColorMatrix(){return colorMatrix;}` ?

Comment: Here's a working sample: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b6d9e399aa3ae68. You'd write the functions the same way as before, except that function declarations outside the class declaration must be preceded by the template header. ```template<int N, int M, typename T>``` in this case.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for the examples !